# How to restore SQL Server database to a particular time?

Tags: sql-server, restore

Is it possible for me to restore a SQL Server 2019 database up to a particular datetime? The database backup is full backup.

The database is full recovery mode, and only one transaction log backup after the full backup.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? It comes with plenty of [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)

Comment: You would have to restore the _entire_ full backup with norecovery and then restore transaction logs using the `STOPAT` parameter.  Then you would bring the database online by finally issuing restore database with recovery.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it through T-SQL this way:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK' 
WITH NORECOVERY
GO 
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.TRN' 
WITH RECOVERY, 
STOPAT = 'Mar 23, 2009 05:31:00 PM' 
GO
```

But don't forget you can use the GUI from SSMS. The graphical solution is easier to understand especially if you are 4 people around the same monitor and the manager is behind you with a stick in his hand:

1. Right click on the database > Tasks > Restore > Database

[image]

2. General > Timeline and setup the time for database restoration

[image]

3. Check in “Specific date and time” to set up the time for database restoration, press “OK” to save changes, and press “OK” button in the previous window

[image]

Comment: He cannto do this as all he has is full backup. First, we don't know if his database is in full recovery mode, second he has no transazction log backups

Comment: @sepupic, thank you, let me rephrase that